# Virtual Machines and UUID changing

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, clone, uuid

Where I work, we are attempting to implement a VM cloning solution for some of our machines. We have a piece of software that needs to be on the cloned image. When I clone the VM the software throws an error saying that the machine hardware has been changed and the software can not start. I've done some research and this seems to be tied to the hardware UUID of the VM. However, there doesn't seem to be a good way to change the hardware UUID in the VM manager. So I'm left with trying to change the UUID inside windows itself to match the original image that the clone VM was made from. Is it possible to manually change the UUID inside of windows to match that of the original machine?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about being able to do this, and in my department, we have to manually install software that has this restriction with the UUID post clone. Like VNC Server.

So take a look at https://www.smartdeploy.com

My IT department has started using this, opposed to having tons of wim files for the various machines and then cloning the image to a partition.

You create one image and have the software and drivers you want to install on the server, and smart deploy does the rest! Making for a truly unattended cloning solution!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortuantly typical cloning isn't the best option for what we are doing. We have several machines that don't sit on our primary network but actually run adhac temp networks for simulation environments. For this reason, having a non-network based solution would be ideal. The reason we are looking into vm cloning as the primary way of this is to ultmialty have multiple instances running simultaniously from the same box.

Comment: Wish I could be more help. Best of wishes to you!